# Controlling the digital input of a frequency inverter with an Arduino

Tags: motor

I am starting a project in which I want to control the digital inputs of a frequency inverter with an Arduino.

[Here's the data sheet.](https://www.hitachi-ies.co.jp/english/products/inv/nes1/doc/NE-S1QuickReferenceGuide.pdf)

The pins take in a maximum voltage of 24V and 100mA. The input pins have a input resistance of 4.7kOhms.

I am not an expert in electronics, but my guess is that since the Arduino has a working voltage of 5V, I'd probably need something in between the Arduino and the frequency inverter.

What is required to interface the two?

Comment: Can you link to a specific data sheet? What is the "ON" level of the input for the inverter? Are these just on/off or do you need something like PWM?

Comment: Do you know how many hundreds of different interface specs this could be? Or did you have precisely one in mind?  Give every detail that matters what you can do and where you are having difficulties after trying. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTVLs.png

Comment: _"The pins **take in** a maximum voltage of 24V and 100mA. The input pins have a input resistance of 4.7kOhms_ - not making sense. Please supply model number and/or specifications of the particular inverter you are using.

Comment: ok I am editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you would want to use the VFD's MODBUS interface.

For an electrical connection you would need an [RS-485 driver](https://www.hwhardsoft.de/english/projects/rs485-arduino/), preferably a galvanically isolated one since VFDs are notoriously electrically noisy.

For the software, you would need a MODBUS library, which is easy to find online.

Then you would need to study the VFD manual to determine what instructions to send to the VFD to make it do what you want.

Comment: thanks I will try it out.